# Set the default Audio track and Subtitle Track with MP4Box

Tags: video, mp4, mp4box

I was recently remuxing some multilingual MP4s and I noticed that in the original audio track, most media players will recognize an audio stream as having some kind of "default" flag, they don't always respect it, and tend to just play the highest ID # in the file (regardless of stream order), but I was hoping to set that flag so I could be more standard.

My current MP4Box command that I'm running for every file in the directory is:

`MP4Box -add "%%a#1" -add "%%a#5" -add "%%a#8" -set-track-id 5:2 -set-track-id 8:3 "output_folder\!file_name!"`

(%%a being the input file path)

I can of course do it with other software, for example, ffmpeg has the `-disposition:a:1 default` flag, but I was wondering if MP4Box offered something similar, perhaps with the `txtflags` option that I believe can set options for subtitles, or maybe the `tkhd` flag for track headers.

Anyone know if this is doable in MP4Box?

Comment: GPAC maintainer here. Please open an issue at https://github.com/gpac/gpac/issues/. I'm not able to help but other people may help you there! If you do so, make sure you put a link to the github issue here.

Comment: I've converted the above from an answer... though... what's the relationship between GPAC and MP4box?

Comment: GPAC is a repo of multiple related tools, one of which is MP4Box.

Opened an issue: https://github.com/gpac/gpac/issues/2585